# Error 13 VBA in simple find and replace

Tags: string, vba, excel

I am new at programmming, so sorry if my question is boring.

I am trying to create a macro that checks for string "Meh" in a range of cells and substitutes the cell above it for "BlahBlah"

So far my code:

```
Sub Findandreplace()


Dim E As String, Wide As Range, R As Range

E = "Meh"

Set Wide = Range("A1:CM300")

For Each R In Wide

    If InStr(R.Value, "Meh") > 0 Then
        R.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "BlahBLah"

End If
```

It worked the first time i run it, but now it gives me an error type 13 in the if sentence. I know I have to dim something, but don´t know what.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The mismatch is that Instr expects a String, but you give it a Variant (R.Value). It usually works, but not always. You could force it to always be a string with CStr(R.Value).

Comment: This code won't work if you find the target string in row 1. The code would try to write the replacement string to the non-existent row 0 and an error would occur. Should the search range be "A2:CM300" instead?

Answer (score 2):

No you dont have to `Dim` anything. By the way variable names are terrible.

You get type mis match error when the cell value itself is error (like #N/A, #DIV/0!)

Check that in your code with `IsError`

```
Sub test()
Dim E As String, Wide As Range, R As Range

E = "Meh"

Set Wide = Range("A1:CM300")

For Each R In Wide

    '/ Check if the cell contains an error.
    If Not IsError(R) Then
        If InStr(R.Value, E) > 0 Then
            R.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "BlahBLah"
        End If
    End If
Next


End Sub
```